# Use Python 3.6.0 in circleci

Tags: python, integration, circleci, pyenv, python-3.6

I am starting new project with python 3.6 and i want to attach circleci to my project.

my circle.yml is

```
machine:
  timezone:
    Asia/Seoul

  python:
    version: 3.6.0

dependencies:
  pre:
    - pip install -r requirements/ci.txt

test:
  post:
    - python manage.py test
```

and circleci error

```
python-build: definition not found: 3.6.0

The following versions contain `3.6.0' in the name:
  3.6.0b1

See all available versions with `pyenv install --list'.

If the version you need is missing, try upgrading pyenv:

  cd /opt/circleci/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/../.. && git pull && cd -

((if (or (= "3.6.0" "system") (pyenv versions --bare | grep -x -q "'3.6.0'")) (pyenv global "3.6.0") (chain-and (pyenv install --skip-existing "" "3.6.0") (pyenv global "3.6.0") (pyenv rehash) (pip install virtualenv) (pip install nose) (pip install pep8) (pyenv rehash)))) returned exit code 2

Action failed: set python version to 3.6.0
```

it seems circleci does not support latest pyenv version.

how do i fix it?

Comment: I suppose you will have to use the beta version until CircleCI supports the final release.

Comment: can i install latest version of pyenv in circleci?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Python 3.6.0 in CircleCI (in the default Ubuntu 14.04 image) right now by having the following in `circle.yml`:

```
machine:                                                                                                                                                                 
  pre:                                                                                                                                                                   
    - cd /opt/circleci/.pyenv; git pull                                                                                                                                  
  python:                                                                                                                                                                
    version: 3.6.0
```

What you are giving up here is about 2 minutes of build time though. This is a workaround, if you NEED 3.6.0, until the new CCI Ubuntu 14.04 image comes out within the next 3 weeks or so.

Comment: This seems strange, I get: cd /opt/circleci/.pyenv; git pull
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/extras/bash_zsh_support/chpwd/function.sh: line 5: cd: /opt/circleci/.pyenv: No such file or directory
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

cd /opt/circleci/.pyenv; git pull returned exit code 128

Action failed: cd /opt/circleci/.pyenv; git pull

Comment: Neither `3.6.5` nor `3.6.4` are available in 2018 :/

Comment: In 2018 CircleCI 2.0 should be used, which supports any Python version.

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this question today, CircleCI has fixed this so now the standard config works through Python 3.6.1.  For example, my `circle.yml` to use 3.6.1:

```
machine:
  python:
    version: 3.6.1

...
```

Comment: @Inti Can you share what error(s) you're seeing using this syntax?

Comment: ```python-build: definition not found: 3.6.1

See all available versions with `pyenv install --list'.

If the version you need is missing, try upgrading pyenv:

  cd /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/../.. && git pull && cd -

((if (or (= "3.6.1" "system") (pyenv versions --bare | grep -x -q "'3.6.1'")) (pyenv global "3.6.1") (chain-and (pyenv install --skip-existing "" "3.6.1") (pyenv global "3.6.1") (pyenv rehash) (pip install virtualenv) (pip install nose) (pip install pep8) (pyenv rehash)))) returned exit code 2

Action failed: set python version to 3.6.1```

Comment: Adding```pre:                                                                                                                                                                   
    - cd /opt/circleci/.pyenv; git pull``` sorted it out for now though

Comment: @Inti It looks like you may be experience a bug on CircleCI. Here are links to my complete [circle.yml](https://github.com/astronomerio/boa/blob/master/circle.yml) and the [build](https://circleci.com/gh/astronomerio/boa) using 3.6.1.

Comment: @Inti In OP's question, the dependency install command is configured in `dependencies > pre` and the test runner command is in `test > post`.  I believe these should be configured as `dependencies > override` and `test > override` as they are replacing vs augmenting Circle's inferred commands.  That may make a difference.